# How should i store multiple values of a model field in the database?

Tags: html, mysql, sql, django

i am creating a stocks website using django. i want to display prices of different stocks in the webpage. i want store the prices of stocks at different dates. there are 100 stocks with 20 different prices for them. i want to display them at different intervals

i want store these 20 different prices of these stocks in the database. so that i can select which price to display manually. i want to store the 20 different prices of the stock and display any one of them using querysets

One solution i tried is i listed all the different prices in an excel file and whenever i wanted to display a different price i import it using python shell

another solution was create a price1,price2....price20 field in the model. this is a very poor solution though i guess

another solution i thought was i could create different databases for the different values and use the 'using' method to query them whichever is required

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Stocks(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10,null='true',blank='true')
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    currentprice = models.FloatField()
    change = models.FloatField()
    lastprice = models.FloatField()
    updated = models.BooleanField(default='False',null='true')
    percent = models.FloatField(null='true',blank='true')
    marketcap = models.FloatField(null='true',blank='true')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker
```

i want to store the 20 different prices of the stock and display any one of them using querysets

Comment: Add a Price class to your models file and add a many-to-one (ForeignKey) relation from the Price class to the Stocks class. Here you can find more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: What do you mean with `null='true'`? Shouldn't this be `null=True`?